# delete image from server, fix google error for that with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

i delete one image from my page and from google now i get error: "image not found".
What i need to do, that google forget this picture?

I need add 404 eroor with this picture link in .htaccess?

```
Redirect 404 /my-picture.png
```

This fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default server should throw 404 when missing files are requested for. So it will be removed from Google index on subsequent crawls.

If you want to get it removed immediately, create a Google Webmaster account, add your site to dashboard. Once done you can submit all images/URLs which are not there anymore to Google and it will be removed from Google Search index.